# How to serialize an IEnumerable like a regular class?

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, json.net

I need to convert an object of `Computer` type to a json string and write it to a file.

The problem that I'm facing is that, due to Computer implementing `IEnumerable` interface for purposes that are out of the scope of this question, the resulted json after serialization contains those pieces of data that are provided by my custom enumerator, although I'm looking to get object's properties (like how the ususal serialization happens with regular classes).

Here is how it behaves **vs** how I want it to behave:

Computer class:

```
class Computer : IEnumerable
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string TeamViewerID { get; set; }
    public string TeamViewerPassword { get; set; }
    // and other properties

    public List<CPU> CPUs { get; set; }
    public List<GPU> GPUs { get; set; }
    public List<PSU> PSUs { get; set; }
    // and other collection properties

    // This Enumerator allows me to iterate thorugh Computer's collection properties
    // CPUs, GPUs, PSUs etc. as PropertyInfo
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new DeviceCollectionPropertyEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Serialization

```
// computerInstance is of type Computer (duh)
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(computerInstance);
```

This is the json that I get

```
[
    {
        "Name": "GPUs",
        "AssemblyName": "SystemInfoCollector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "ClassName": "SystemInfoCollector.Models.Computer",
        "Signature": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SystemInfoCollector.Models.GPU] GPUs",
        "Signature2": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[SystemInfoCollector.Models.GPU, SystemInfoCollector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] GPUs",
        "MemberType": 16,
        "GenericArguments": null
    },
    {
        "Name": "PSUs",
        "AssemblyName": "SystemInfoCollector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "ClassName": "SystemInfoCollector.Models.Computer",
        "Signature": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SystemInfoCollector.Models.PSU] PSUs",
        "Signature2": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[SystemInfoCollector.Models.PSU, SystemInfoCollector, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] PSUs",
        "MemberType": 16,
        "GenericArguments": null
    },

    // And the rest of collection properties of Computer type ...
    // This is the stuff that is provided by DeviceCollectionPropertyEnumerator
]
```

The json that **I would love to see** (I can get this if I get rid of IEnumerable implementation)

```
{
    "Identifier": "213231",
    "TeamViewerID": null,
    "TeamViewerPassword": null,
    ...
    "CPUs": [],
    "GPUs": [],
    "PSUs": [],
    ...
}
```

I guess my custom Enumerator overrides the behaviour of getting properties out of a Computer instance on serialization. How to overcome this? How to serialize this Computer just like any other regular class that does not implement `IEnumerator`?

I use .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: That `: IEnumerable` makes Computer a list of computers, which is very very weird. Are you sure that `IEnumerable` should be there? A computer has list of parts, but it's not itself a list of such parts

Comment: implementing `IEnumerable` is throwing off JSON.NET - try not implementing it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that your `Computer` implements `IEnumerable`, as it's not a collection. Ask yourself this: "Is a computer a non generic collection?", the answer is no. What I would do is expose a `public IEnumerable<IPcComponent> Components` and make your individual components implement `IPcComponent` if your *really* need to iterate over all components of a PC

Comment: No, wait. I use `IEnumerable` to apply the Iterator design pattern when it comes to iterating though computer's components, and there are several parts in my codebase where I have to iterate only though component properties (components = list of cpus, gpus, etc.) and, for that, I've created a custom enumerator that allows me to iterate over those properties like this: `foreach(PropertyInfo componentCollection in computer) { // do stuff }`, there is nothing wrong in having IEnumerable implemented here, the problem is serialization :)

Comment: It isn't that your design is _bad_ - but it is _unusual_. And serializers tend to handle unusual things - well, unusually. I think @MindSwipe's solution is likely the simplest one. Add an extra property for `IEnumerable`, exclude it from JSON serialisation, and away you go.

Comment: @MindSwipe Indeed it is a collection, it's a collection of component list properties. I'm not looking to get the components (like a list of cpus or something), I need the property itself representing that list.

Comment: `// This Enumerator allows me to iterate thorugh Computer's collection properties
    // CPUs, GPUs, PSUs etc. as PropertyInfo` Ask yourself this - what other types have you seen that act that way?

Comment: Well, saying "A Computer is and always will be a collection of `PropertyInfo`s consisting of the properties which contain the components" is incorrect. If you really, desperately need a list of `PropertyInfo` then create a method like `public IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetComponentProperties() { ... }`. Because right now, what you're telling JSON.Net is that "this class is a collection, serialize my content (which you get by `foreach`ing over me) into a JSON array", which it's doing and (correctly) serializing the `PropertyInfos`

Comment: P.S anything that needs `PropertyInfo` to get access to individual properties looks like bad architecture

Comment: I see where this is going :) I'm working on a legacy project, I don't want to rewrite everything. It's an WPF application that renders those lists of components on UI, and it does it using reflection => we foreach the computer, aka we only go through  props that interest us, and render them. It might not be a good design, but we've sacrificed it prioritizing flexibility (ex: If the CPU's frequency is needed, just add the `Frequency` field to the CPU and it will be automatically fetched, rendered etc, without writing a single line line of code anywhere else). K then, refactoring incoming :) Thx

Comment: I thought this is the right way of implementing Iterator Pattern (I still think so, change my mind :). Indeed it seems strange to treat the computer as a collection it's components, but here is another example: I have a house, and I want to iterate over house's furniture that are made out of wood but the pieces of furniture are represented via house props, how would you do that? I think in this case creating an enumerator is the right and most intuitive decision, although I'm not sure about that, I seems like a very interested topic to talk about when I go for a beer with my fellas :)

Comment: `I still think so, change my mind` If your current pain isn't convincing to you, I doubt our other arguments will be. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach the [JsonObjectAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonObjectAttributeOverrideIEnumerable.htm) to your Computer type:

```
[JsonObject]
class Computer : IEnumerable
```

This will force serialization to serialize it like an object and not a collection, thus ignoring `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>` altogether.

Note that this will completely ignore the `IEnumerable` part so whatever would be serialized through that collection support will either have to be ignored, or handled through those properties as you showed.

---

As comments on your question have already stated, it seems like a strange design to make a computer an implicit collection of its components. Since you've stated it is legacy code you're hoping not to disturb too much, and only want to fix the Json.net serialization, you can use that attribute to circumvent the automatic collection serialization.