# Controlling how Text.Json.JsonSerializer serializes an object that implements a generic collection interface

Tags: serialization, system.text.json, jsonserializer

I have encountered a problem serialising an object to JSON.

The object is set up with serialisable fields and properties, but it also implements a generic collection interface:

In a simplified form, it essentially looks like this:

```
class MyClass : IEnumerable<IMyInterface>
{
  [JsonConstructor] public MyClass {}
  [JsonInclude] public List<MyObj> Entries { get; set; } = new List<MyObj> ();
}

class MyObj : IMyInterface
{ 
  [JsonInclude] public string strValue;
  [JsonIgnore] public bool ExampleProp => false;
}

public interface IMyInterface
{
  string strValue;
  bool ExampleProp { get; }
}
```

The problem arises because Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize seems to choose to serialise the MyClass instance as an IEnumerable - thus ending up including the ExampleProp value - rather than as a MyClass object.

I have not been able to identify any way to control this behaviour; my only option seems to be to refactor and eliminate the IEnumerable interface (e.g. bury it in a property or method).

Does anyone know of some way to control how JsonSerializer makes these choices?

Comment: This is not currently implemented as of .NET 7.  You will need to create a custom converter or refactor your design.  See [System.Text.Json: How to serialise an IEnumerable like a regular class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74615202).

Comment: How many times it was told that anybody who decided to use a collection as a basic class  is looking for the problems.

Comment: Also, see [Why not inherit from List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193) for reasons why the design should be refactored.

Comment: Thank you, @dbc; some very useful pointers there.